# Cloudy pillar or pillar of cloud

Tags: grammar, differences, dictionaries

Could someone help me understand the difference between a cloudy pillar and a pillar of cloud? I know they could be used synonymously, but I want to know if there is any discrapancy between the two in english.

Comment: Is a cloudy day a day of clouds??

Comment: @Lambie Actually, one *could* put it that way. :)

Comment: Please provide the context. Where have you encountered these terms? What are they describing? In fact, neither phrase sounds natural to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **cloudy pillar** would be a pillar that is cloudy (sorry). Where the pillar could be made of stone, metal or anything else. Cloudy has many meanings, some fairly metaphorical. For example:

> dimmed or dulled as if by clouds a cloudy mirror
>
> uneven in color or texture

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cloudy)

So it could be a stone pillar carved with a pattern of clouds. Or a wooden pillar obscured by clouds. Or a mirrored pillar that needs cleaning. Or a glass pillar filled with a cloudy liquid. Or, even, a pillar made of cloud.

On the other hand, **pillar of cloud** means a pillar made of cloud (or a cloud in the shape of a pillar). It *could* be intended metaphorically, but that would only be obvious from the context.